# Removing PHP extension and forcing HTTPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

I'm wondering how I can go around forcing HTTPS across my site and all it's directories and also removing any .PHP extension. I had the following code in my .htaccess file but in some directories I would get a 404 even although they do exist.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.motherwellelim.org.uk/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For redirect site from http to https, use this

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

and you can easily remove extension by following this code.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

make sure you have enabled rewrite_module.